# How can I save a graphics style from a pre-designed ai file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-conversion, graphic-styles

Hello I am new to graphics design. I have downloaded ai file. And now I want to save its neon light graphics style. how can I save it ? Is it possible to save ? If possible please help me how can I save it. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Just save the file and styles will be retained. To transfer the style to another object use the eyedropper tool. If all styles don't transfer examine the Appearance tab for the original object, look at the neon glow settings and reproduce them on your new object.

Comment: Can you please explain it in more detailed

Comment: If you have an .ai file with styles you want to keep, if you save it as an .ai the styles will still be there the next time you open it. If you want to apply the neon style to another object then select that object, select the eyedropper tool and sample the neon. If that doesn't work then go into the appearances panel with the neon glow selected and you can see the style, what was used to make the style. Illustrator comes with a bunch of canned neon glow styles, find them in  Graphic Style Libraries>Neon Effects. Try some of those and see if they are the effect you want.